# What would be faster: Spliting a 64-bit word into 16 nibbles and entering them in S-Boxes or using an entire 64-bit word directly as an entry?

Tags: performance, cpu-word, block-cipher, cpu-cycles, nibble

This question is related to cryptography, but I believe I'm asking in right place (not in Crypto Stackexchange).

Kuznyechik block cipher splits a 64-bit word into 16 nibbles (4-bits) and use them as entries in its S-Boxes, each nibble is mixed with 2048-bytes of data in its S-Box set, totaling in 32768-bytes processed per each 64-bit word. There is an example here: https://github.com/veracrypt/VeraCrypt/blob/master/src/Crypto/kuznyechik.c#L2147-L2149

But let's suppose I want to use a 64-bit word directly.

What would be faster (I mean, use less CPU cycles):

Spliting a 64-bit word into 16 nibbles and mixing each of them into a 2048-bytes S-Boxes each (totaling 32768-bytes processed in total 16 nibbles) **OR** Mixing an entire 64-bit word into S-Boxes of 32768-bytes without any splitting??

/\ Remembering, is the same size of bytes mixed into the two cases.

Comment: The first problem is that you'd need a total of 8589934592 hard drives (with 4 TIB of capacity each) just to store the S-Box. If you assume 10 watts per hard drive it adds up to about 85 nuclear reactors just to power them.

Comment: Ops, one more thing I learn. I didn't know that S-box to be invertible need only one single byte because using 16, 24 or 64 would require huge S-Boxes. Thanks for your clarification! =)